# use JDK of Netbeans for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, netbeans, android-studio

My School has restricted the installation of the JDK but they installed the following:

- JRE (Java Runtime Environment)
- NetBeans
- Eclipse

I want to install Android Studio and develop apps on their computers. I can install the software successfully but Android Studio won't accept the JRE, it needs to know where the JDK is.

Do IDE's like NetBeans come with built-in JDK's which i can use for Android Studio aswell? And if so, can I use them as source for Android Studio?

cheers!
phil

Comment: A JDK might be installed on another machine and only the JDK directory copied on another machine. This means there is no integration with Winodw/browser plugins and such. Of course the java from that directory then must be used.

Comment: @JoopEggen Are you saying they might have the JDK on a server?
would NetBeans even work without JDK?
Can i somehow get the Path to the JDK within Netbeans or Eclipse?

Comment: In NetBeans (8) you can find the jdk(s) by going to Tools > Java Platforms in NetBeans. And no Netbeans doesn't come with a build in JDK; *JDK 7 and later versions are required for installing and running the Java SE, Java EE and All NetBeans Bundles. You can download standalone JDK ...* (cited https://netbeans.org/downloads/?pagelang=)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think IDE's like NetBeans exists with built-in JDK's!

-> I guess the JDK is located on the server and you do not have access as long as you do not know the exact path!

-> Try to somehow find out the path to the JDK, then you can use the Path

Comment: You were right, my school stores the JDK on a shared folder i could set JAVA_HOME to the UNC path.